# yaml file script for running axe web accessibility test

Tags: javascript, azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines, playwright

> Since I am new to azure devops,I am working on existing azure pipeline
> which has artifacts > of npm install, npm build and publish
> artifacts:drop.  How can I add tasks to the existing pipeline to
> perform web accessibilty using axe playwright, which performs similar
> task as the below code -

```
import { chromium, Browser, Page } from 'playwright'
import { test } from '@playwright/test';
import { injectAxe, checkA11y, } from 'axe-playwright'

let browser: Browser
let page: Page

test.describe('Playwright web page accessibility test', () => {
  test.beforeAll(async () => {
    browser = await chromium.launch()
    page = await browser.newPage()
    await page.goto(`http://localhost:4000`)
    await injectAxe(page)
  })

  test('simple accessibility run', async () => {
    await checkA11y(page, null, {
      axeOptions: {
        runOnly: {
          type: 'tag',
          values: ['best-practice'],
        },
      },
    detailedReport: true,
      detailedReportOptions: { html: true },
    })
  })
```

> Need script similar to add in yaml file like the below for lint, test

```
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- task: NodeTool@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '14.16.1'
  displayName: 'Install Node.js'

- script: |
    npm install
  displayName: 'npm install'

- script: |
    npx eslint --max-warnings=0 src || exit 1
  displayName: 'lint code'

- script: |
    npm test -- --watchAll=false || exit 1
  displayName: 'unit test'
```

Comment: Does it help? https://learndevtestops.com/2022/07/28/playwright-azure-devops-amazing-microsoft-family/

Comment: @KrzysztofMadej the above link will install playwright and run test, but I was looking axe playwright web accessibility test which may be next step